# JavaScript addEventListener 'click''

Tags: javascript, navbar

I struggling with very basic thing

I am trying to make this side-nav appear and disappear with JavaScript. The code below only activates the nav bar but doesn't deactivate it. Tried all options but I don't know how to call function to close nav-bar.

Thank you

```
HTML


    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
     <a href="#" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
     <a href="#">About</a>
     <a href="#">Services</a>
     <a href="#">Clients</a>
     <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

     <!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
      <span id="MyElement">&times;</span>


JS


        <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";

    }
    window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("MyElement").addEventListener('click',changeClass);
    }
</script>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You have multiple ID with same value you need to change so that every ID will be unique

Comment: *or*, if you intend to hook up the same logic to multiple elements, use a class name instead of an id, and hook them up to all elements that roll out of `Document.getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: Do a `console.log(menu.style.width);` just to check that the value actually is a string. And I would change the `else if` to a simple `else`. No need to check the actual size.

Comment: Hey i consle.log it and it is a string.

Comment: @MarekMaszay so if i change <a href="#" class="closebtn" id="MyElement">&times;</a> to let's say id="another Element" how should i refer is in JS that i can close nav?

Comment: @Damien `document.getElementById("another Element").addEventListener('click',toggleMenu);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `else` statement section seems to have the comparator (`==`) and assignment (`=`) the wrong way around :

```
   } else if (menu.style.width = "250px") {
        menu.style.width == "-250px";
   }
```

looks like it should be

```
   } else if (menu.style.width == "250px") {
        //setting a negative width will immediately break the toggle logic.
        //just set it to 0px.
        menu.style.width = "0px"; 
   }
```

Full example :

```js
function changeClass() {
        var sidenavElement = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
        if(sidenavElement.style.width == "0px")
        {
           sidenavElement.style.width = "250px";
        }
        else
        {
          sidenavElement.style.width = "0px";
        }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("MyElement").addEventListener('click',changeClass);
    }
```

```css
#mySidenav
{
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" style="width:0px">
  HELLO I AM SIDENAV
</div>

<button id="MyElement">toggle it</button>
```

Comment: did you resolve the problem with having multiple elements that have the same `id` in your page?

Comment: i also noticed you're using `let`. is the browser you are running this in capable of Javascript/ES6? if not, try using `var` instead.

Comment: ` <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggleMenu() {
            var menu = document.getElementById('mySidenav');
            if (menu.style.width == "0px") {
                menu.style.width = "250px";
            } else {
                menu.style.width = "0px";
            }
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("MyElement").addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
        }
    </script>`

Comment: `<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="#" class="closebtn" id="Element">&times;</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Clients</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
    <span id="MyElement">&times;</span>`

Comment: i have change the `id` but how to call this to close nav?

Comment: Ok, you'll still need to add a listener to the element outside of the menu first then ; so add `document.getElementById("another Element").addEventListener('click',toggleMenu)` to your `window.onload`

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeClass() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";

        }
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("MyElement").addEventListener('click', changeClass);
         }
    </script>`

Comment: above code is opening nav-bar i have button with `class="close` how to implement it?

Comment: @Damien please stop trying to post all of your code in the comments, it's hardly readable, and the code you just posted isn't even complete.

Comment: just updated source code in question to reflect current sate. This code is displaying nav-bar how to make it disapper?

Comment: @Damien i added a complete example.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't have to objects with the same ID (use name instead?)
2. You have a typo in `else if` with comparator mark and another in the next line with assingment mark.
3. Since in `menu.style.width == "-250px"` you would be assigning value to -250 `(menu.style.width == "0px)` would never pass and it would keep assigning value `-250` whenever someone clicks the button, but that fails, because you have a typo in your assingment mark.
4. Width cannot be negative
5. Is `let` compatable with your browser?
6. Have you considered using `display:none` and `display:block` (or whatever display you have)?

> ```
> function toggleMenu() {
>     var menu = document.getElementById('mySidenav');
>     if (menu.style.display == "none")
>          menu.style.display = "inline-block"; //block
>     else
>          menu.style.display = "none";
> }
>
> window.onload = function() {
>     document.getElementById("MyElement").onclick = toggleMenu;
> }
> ```

Comment: giving them the same `name` is just as bad. this is what `class` is for.

Comment: Depending wheter it's for styling or accessing. The point is that it's illegal to have 2 objects with the same ID. At least it won't error.

Comment: having two elements with the same `id` or `name` won't throw everything to a grinding halt, no, but it's not considered valid. you are also confusing assignment and comparison in your example code btw.

Comment: Excuse me, am I? In my 3rd point I just copyed his code. Did you even read it all or did you stop at 1st line?

Comment: you didn't ; this is straight from your post : > Since in menu.style.width == "-250px" you would be assigning value to -250  ... 
but that line does not assign anything at all

Comment: That's why I used `would`, read till end. I thought this was an intelegent comunity. Seems I was wrong..

Comment: Look, i'm trying to help *you* post a helpful answer. this is plain unreadable, and an amalgamation of the answers by everyone else before you. I'd encourage you to post helpful answers on SO rather than berate somebody who's trying to help you. Pick your battles.

Comment: When I started typing there were no comments or answers. Your points are ridiculous. If you wanted your answer to be the only one, I'm sorry to disapoint you.

Comment: again ; (and this is the last time) this is not about kicking down someone else's answer in favor of my own. If you think that is what we do on SO, you're very, very wrong. If you think we'd get away with that, *you'd be even more wrong*. that having been said ; 
Even if you would've been the first to answer, i'd feel the need to downvote this answer because : -it is unclear, -it is full of typo's (even in the code. did you try running it?) -it uses made up words (assignation should be "assignment", i think)

Comment: what you do with this answer is your *own choice*. if you think i'm selling you bullsh@t, keep it the way it is. if you think i might have a point, improve your answer and possibly earn an upvote instead of a downvote. *that* is how it works.

Comment: Finaly a valid point, I should've used `assignment`, sorry if my grammar makes my code not work 4 you.

Comment: your grammar has nothing to do with your code not working; that is your typing and spelling.

Comment: `document.getElementById("MyElement").onclick = toogleMenu;` should read `toggleMenu`

Comment: Mhm, good point. But why argue about ridiculous points for 46 minutes?

Comment: well, did we learn anything? if yes, then i'd say 46 minutes could have been spent worse ;) congrats on your first upvote. (i could have just downvoted, left and not looked back. which is better?)

Answer (score 1):

There is many problem in your code, you have 2 elements inside your DOM with same ID as mentioned by Marek Maszay.

Your `else` statement should use `==` in condition and `=` for assignation.

Last thing, you should not use `width` property to display or not an element there is a `display` property in css

```
  <html>
    <body>
      <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <span class="closebtn" id="MyElement">&times;</span>
        <span id="menu">
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </span>
      </div>

     <!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
      <span id="MyElement2">&times;</span>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function toggleMenu() {
                let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
                if (menu.style.display == "") { 
                    menu.style.display = "none";
                } else if (menu.style.display == "none") {
                    menu.style.display = "";
                }
            }

      window.onload = function() {   
      document.getElementById("MyElement").addEventListener('click',toggleMenu);
         }
        </script>
        ...

    </body>

    </html>
```

When `display` value is "", it take the default display value of an element, when its value is `none` the element is not displayed.

Here is your code modified.

**EDIT**

For some reason changing width to 0px doesn't hide the element. Element change from line to column, it seem that the browser try to fill element with content and put at least one word per line.

Seem like other people on web are having same problem.

Comment: He could be trying to animate the width with a CSS transition, so `width` vs `display` isn't really the issue here i think.

Comment: Maybe i maid an unclear answer if people understand that width can't work ?
But semantically, using display to hide element is better for other people reading your code, you can still animate width and change the display value if you want an animation ^^
And in some case you may want to alter the width of an element hided without displaying it.
Depend on your use case :)

Comment: Yes display is not an issue

Comment: @Nolyurn i'm not saying your solution is bad, or wouldn't work ; it looks like it works fine :) and i agree keeping it simple is often the best think to do.
I'm just saying maybe this isn't the way OP intended to tackle the issue.

Comment: The reason for setting the width to `0` not hiding the contents is because `overflow` is still visible on the element. adding `overflow:hidden` to its style or css class achieves the desired effect when using `width`.

Comment: `overflow:hidden` will hide the content but there will still be blank line